# How to modify array of product collection before rendering category page?

Tags: magento-2.0, product-collection, product-view

I trying to figure out how to modify some rows in product collection before it will be rendered at category page. I'm digging around `getProductListHtml()` `(module-catalog/Block/Category/View.php)` but no success.

Comment: You can maybe use the observer `catalog_block_product_list_collection` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify product collection before rendering category page follow these steps:

1. Override `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`
2. In function `_getProductCollection` after `if` statement insert your code:

```
    $collection = $this->_productCollection;
    foreach ($collection as $k => $product){
        // Here goes your code to modify product
        // For example:
        $newName = $product->getName().' (HOT SALE)';// just example guys
        $product->setName($newName);
        $collection->removeItemByKey($k);// Remove original item from collection
        $collection->addItem($product);// Add modified item to collection
    }
    $collection->setOrder('position','ASC');// Reorder collection as you want
```

Comment: It's always best to use a Plugin as much as possible. Only use Preference if there's no other choice. For this, you can just even use an after Plugin to manipulate the result of the getLoadedProductCollection method.